Isn't there any more efficient solution for the CodeForces 919-B/Perfect Number question?
So, here's the question:

We consider a positive integer perfect, if and only if the sum of its digits is exactly 10. Given a positive integer k, your task is to find the k-th smallest perfect positive integer.
Input: A single line with a positive integer k (1≤k≤10000).
Output: A single number, denoting the k-th smallest perfect integer.

The solution I've got for this question is:
int main(){
    int k=0, m=19, c=0, sum=0;
    scanf("%d", &k);
    while(true){
        int n = m;
        sum = 0;
        while(n){
            sum+=n%10;
            n=n/10;
        }
        // printf("%d %d %d\n", n, sum, c);
        if(sum == 10) c++;
        if(c == k) break;
        m++;
    }
    printf("%d", m);
    return 0;
}

So, isn't there any solution that is more efficient than this one ?
I've thought about this problem for about an hour and then decided to google the answer. This solution truly disappointed me. I've expected that there will be some tricky math hidden in this problem.

"We consider a positive integer perfect, if and only if the sum of its digits is exactly 10" - are you sure this is the definition?  It is very different that the common one. See: Perfect Number (equal to the sum of its positive proper divisors).

@wohlstad I think this definition of perfect number is defined only for the purpose of this question.

At the very least, there would be no need to increase m by 1 (2 consecutive numbers cannot be perfect). It should be double-checked but I think numbers are multiples of 9 iif the sum of their digit is a multiple of 9, making perfect numbers those that are 1 + a multiple of 9. With that in mind, there are probably some patterns to be exploited such as (also need to be double checked) 10 numbers are perfect between 100 and 199, then 9 numbers are perfect between 200 and 299, then 8 between 300 and 399, ... 2 between 900 and 999, then 10 between 1000 and 1099, 9 between 1100 and 1199 etc...

@Atmo maybe we can generate the numbers? There's only so many digit combinations that sum up to 10, which means all the other digits of a "perfect" number must be 0. There might be a way to consistently generate the k-th "perfect" number by finding the pattern to that.

Indeed but there are probably a lot of such combinations and importantly, I do not see how that helps finding the k-th perfect number... Anyway, the question was answered, then edited with a disclaimer saying it is probably incorrect (which it indeed is)... Not sure if the CodeForces problem was incorrectly described by OP though.

@Atmo The Codeforces problem was correctly described; it's just that the answer here is incorrect.

Start with 19. Imagine the numbers with "decimal digit sum" up to 91, figure out how many there are. How many perfect three-digit numbers, are any smaller than 91?

(@Dave The answer here is not a useful way to refer to an answer post. Use the hyperlink(while the user number can't change, the user name can) - I think you referred to irrenhaus3's answer.)

@greybeard Oops! Thanks.

Imagine you want to generate a "perfect" number (for future readers: here, perfect numbers are those whose individual digits sum to 10) under a given 10k, for now ignoring the fact that you want them generated from an index.
An algorithm that lets you do so is:

Start with 0, written with leading zeroes so that the written number is of length k: 0000000000 and k balls in a black box numbered 0 to k-1.
Pick a random ball; its value is i. Increase the ith (by convention from least to most significant digit, starting at 0) by 1.
What you get is e.g 0000000100 for i = 2.
Place the ball back into the box.
Repeat steps 2 and 3, 9 times (for a total of 10x).
By construction, you will get a perfect number such as 0030200410.

While this procedure is random, i.e. is not suitable to generate a "perfect" number from its index, it is useful to understand how many perfect numbers there are between 0 and 10k.
In case you do not know what that number is, I got you covered: it is called combination with repetitions and you can read about it in this Wikipedia article.
Conveniently, the same principle applied to drawing 9, or 8, or 7, etc. balls lets you calculate how many perfect numbers there are between any n1 = 10k i and n2 = 10k (i+1)-1.For example, there are 10 "perfect" numbers between 214000 and 214999 (7 balls drawn, 3 draws to go with 3 balls in the box), 4 between 214000 and 214099 (also 7 balls drawn and 3 more draws to go but with only 2 balls in the box).

Inverting the above principle allows us to count how many "perfect" numbers exist under any given value. Then comparing that count to the input index i enables the generation of the desired result:

Knowing how many numbers there are under 10k, we can tell how many digits the ith perfect number has.
At this step, we must be careful not to count the combinations where the same ball is drawn 10 times (in case you missed it above, this is a real possibility with the combinations with repetitions and it would obviously not work for your problem; e.g. you won't find a 1-digit-long "perfect" number but you can draw 10 times from a box containing 1 ball).
If we do so correctly, we are guaranteed the ball numbered k will be drawn between 1 and 9 times (and as a consequence, none of the other balls can be drawn 10x either).
Knowing how many numbers there are between 10k and 2x10k-1, we can tell if the first digit we look for is 1.
If not, no worries: we repeat the calculation with the range 2x10k to 3x10k-1, then 3x10k to 4x10k-1, etc until reaching 10x10k-1.
Determining the first digit (nk) is like drawing the corresponding number of identical balls from the black box.
Therefore, we only need to keep track of how many balls we still need to draw and work our way down, in decreasing powers of 10.
As we progress and balls with higher values are removed from our box, we eventually end up having only the ball numbered 0 remaining. That forces the unit digit to a unique value (e.g. the temporary result 17_ is forced to become 172)

As the calculation is like forcing balls to be drawn in the descending order of their respective index, the randomness has disappeared.

Here is what it looks like in code; its time complexity is O(log(n)2) (perhaps O(log(n)) but I did not confirm) and its size complexity is O(1). Therefore, it executes nearly instantaneously (<1ms) in the range covered by unsigned long long.I included a time comparison with the function provided in the only (at time of writing) other answer if you want to try (you'll need to copy the kth function from it).
unsigned long long number_sum10(unsigned int index) 
{
    if (index == 0)
        throw std::runtime_error("Input cannot be 0.");

    auto combination_with_replacement = [](unsigned int number, unsigned int chosen = 10) -> unsigned long long
    {
        if (number == 0)
            return 1;
        unsigned long long result = chosen;
        for (decltype(number) i = 1; i < number; ++i) {
            result *= (chosen + i);
            result /= (i + 1);
        }
        return result;
    };

    unsigned int d = 1;
    unsigned long long count = 0, power = 1;
    for (; count < index; ++d) {
// Subtracting 1 from the combination count to avoid counting the invalid draws of 10x the same ball.
        count += combination_with_replacement(d) - 1;
        power *= 10;
    }
// Went 1 digit too far -> subtract to roll it back
    d -= 1;
    count -= combination_with_replacement(d) - 1;

    unsigned long long result = 0, digit = 1, ballsDrawn = 0;
    while (d > 0) {
        while (count < index) {
            auto toAdd = combination_with_replacement(d - 1, 11 - digit - ballsDrawn);
            if (count + toAdd >= index)
                break;
            digit += 1;
            count += toAdd;
        }
        ballsDrawn += digit;
        // Replace the next 2 lines with the commented line below to generate a std::string instead of unsigned long long with.
        result += power * digit;
        power /= 10;
        // result += std::to_string(digit);
        digit = 0;
        d -= 1;
    }

    result += 10 - ballsDrawn;
    return result;
}


#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int main(int, char**)
{
    using std::chrono::steady_clock;
    using std::chrono::duration_cast;
    using std::chrono::duration;
    using std::chrono::milliseconds;

    int k = 10000000;
    auto start = steady_clock::now();
    unsigned long long result1 = number_sum10(k);
    auto mid = steady_clock::now();
    std::string result2 = kth(k);
    auto end = steady_clock::now();
    std::cout << result1 << " vs " << result2 << " (" << (std::to_string(result1) == result2 ? "Same result" : "Unexpected difference") << ")\n";
    std::cerr << "Execution: " << duration_cast<milliseconds>(mid - start).count() << "ms vs " << duration_cast<milliseconds>(end - mid).count() << "ms\n";
}

The function I coded returns an unsigned long long so it will overflow after the 17,809,915th perfect number (18,100,000,000,000,000,000), a.k.a. the greatest "perfect" number under 264 = 18,446,744,073,709,551,616.
To go beyond, you must transform the function in so that:

It returns a string (I placed a commented "helper" line in my code if you want to try).
It returns a larger fixed-width integer type (e.g. boost::multiprecision::uint128_t).
It returns a big integer type from an external library.
I did test a modified version of the function with the bigint_t typed defined in this library; everything looks fine.


Well, you could always do it by dynamic programming.
At each step, let V[s] be the vector of numbers with sum of digits equal to s. (0<=s<=10).
At the next step you form V[s] from each digit d in turn tagged to the front of all elements in Vold[s-d]. If you let d go from 0 to min(9,s) then they will be stored in order. Stop when V[10] has enough elements.
Had to store the numbers as strings, though, as some of the intermediate ones have to have 0 at the front.
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

string kth( int k )
{
   const string digits = "0123456789";
   vector<vector<string>> V( 11 );          // V[s] is the vector of strings whose digits sum to s
   for ( int d = 0; d < 10; d++ ) V[d].emplace_back( string( 1, digits[d] ) );

   while( true )
   {
      auto Vold = V;                                       // previous values with one less digit
      V = vector<vector<string>>( 11 );                    // accumulate values with another digit at the front
      for ( int s = 10; s >= 0; s-- )                      // loop over sum of digits
      {
         for ( int d = 0; d <= min(s,9); d++ )             // loop over the new first digit
         {
            for ( const string &number : Vold[s-d] )       // new sum s from   digit=d + old sum=(s-d)
            {
               V[s].emplace_back( digits[d] + number );
               if ( s == 10 && d != 0 )                    // a "perfect" (ahem!) number found
               {
                  k--;
                  if ( k == 0 ) return V[s].back();
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}


int main()
{
   int k;
// cout << "Enter k: ";
   cin >> k;
   cout << kth( k );
}

Output for k = 10000:
10800100

But with strings you can, at least, go somewhat higher. Output for k=10000000 (ten million) is apparently
1010110000111110010


Your intuition is correct, that solution is a naive bruteforce that works for small cases but grows in O(n²) and so quickly slows down as k grows. There is an O(1) (constant time) solution to this:
The question has come up before on math stackexchange and received a beautiful answer outlining the optimal solution here.
Edit:
I missed the part about the digit sum being exactly 10, not divisible by 10...
In this case I'm not sure if there is an optimization, since you really are fully dependant on all digits in your input. Saša's solution on the math exchange question doesn't apply to your case.
The most I can think of to optimize your case is to break early as soon as your sum exceeds 10, and to split large numbers up into smaller parts and compute their sums in parallel, since they are all independant of each other.

FYI, I have found an optimization. It is not as fast as appending a single digit to a number but still has a better complexity; I think it is in the lines of O(log(n)) or O(log(n)^2) (I have not checked what it precisely was).
